# Pointers to min and max values of a array

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in which there are two pointers that point to the min and the max value of a 100-values array. Why does it give me error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int array[100], i;
    for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        array[i]=i;
    int *ptr1, *ptr2, flag=0;
    ptr1 = &array[0];
    ptr2 = &array[0];
    while(!flag){
        for(i=0;i<100;i++){
            if(*ptr1 > array[i]){
                ptr1 = &array(i);
                break;
            }else if(*ptr2 < array[i]){
                ptr2 = &array(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i==100)
            flag=1;
    }

    printf("%d %d", *ptr1, *ptr2);
}
```

main.c:13:25: error: called object ‘array’ is not a function or function pointer

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish when writing array(i) ?

Comment: You need `&array[i]` instead of `&array(i)`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @aschepler I'm so dumb. Thank you

Comment: I don't see why you wrap the `for` loop in a `while` loop, or why there are `break` statements.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
ptr1 = &array(i);
```

should be corrected to

```
ptr1 = &array[i];
```

So does the

```
ptr2 = &array(i);
```